# Accessing a database using c# and Visual Studio design-time dataset

Tags: c#, dataset, visual-studio-2012, strongly-typed-dataset

I've seen so many ways of accessing a database using C# I don't know which one is "best" for simple reading/writing/manipulating data.  I used to just use generic DataSet/DataTable objects but I'm trying to use more type safe structures.  I've started by adding a dataset (xsd) in visual studio and connecting to a SQL server backend.

I'm trying to query search a column in a table for a given string, but the column isn't the primary key (so i can't use .Find()).  How do i do this?  Do i need to use LINQ or can i use extension methods/lambda expressions?

On a more basic level, when using the design-time dataset do I need to use Table adapters to fill each table in the Dataset I use or do i just instantiate the dataset?  The documentation is a bit confusing to me.

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't just use a parameter query in the tableadapter to locate the row you want, instead of pulling all the data first and then locating it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Linq-To-DataSet` which is the most powerful way (not in terms of efficiency but in terms of readability and maintainability) to query the `DataSet`.

Read more: [Querying Typed DataSets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399351.aspx).

You have the option to create a `TableAdapter` or just a `DataTable` on the VS designer. If you add a TableAdapter VS creates also the according DataTable. If you only add a DataTable, you have to provide your own way to fill it.  `TableAdapters` are similar to a `DataAdapter` in ADO.NET.

So if you have created a DataSet named `DataSet1` and added a TableAdapter which selects a table named `tabData`, Visual Studio will automatically create a DataTable named `tabDataDataTable` and a `TableAdapter` named `tabDataTableAdapter` in the namespace `DataSet1TableAdapters`.

So you could fill this table in this way:

```
var dataSet = new DataSet1();
var da = new DataSet1TableAdapters.tabDataTableAdapter();
da.Fill(dataSet.tabData);
```

Assuming that the table has columns `Name` and `Age` and you want to find all rows where the name starts with `"Jon"` and age is > 30, you can use LINQ's `Where`:

```
var jons = dataSet.tabData
                  .Where(r => r.Name.StartsWith("Jon") && r.Age > 30);
foreach (DataSet1.tabDataRow row in jons)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} is {1} years old", row.Name, row.Age);
}
```

Note that you can use LINQ-To-DataSet type safe(`r.Name` is a string and`r.Age` an int).

Comment: This looks like a good way to read from the DB.  Can Link to DS be used to push data to the database?  That article didn't appear to address that directly.

Comment: @FistOfFury: You can use `Linq-To-Sql` or `Linq-To-Enitites` if you want a real ORM mapper. `Linq-To-DataSet` is just a subset of `Linq-To-Objects` which helps to query objects that are already in memory. You can of course use a `DataAdapter` to update the database from a `DataTable`. But that is ADO.NET and is not directly related to Linq.